# PHP if statement always false

Tags: php

I have a php script which is supposed to register a user. It was working fine two weeks ago but it stopped working today after making minor changes to an unrelated part of the site. Here is the code:

```
<?php

    $salt="mysecretsalt";

    $activationkey = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

    $Firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $Lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];


        function asc2hex ($temp) {
           $data = "";
           $len = strlen($temp);
           for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) $data.=sprintf("%02x",ord(substr($temp,$i,1)));
           return $data;
        }

    $Email = stripslashes($Email);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password2 = stripslashes($password2);
    $Firstname = stripslashes($Firstname);
    $Lastname = stripslashes($Lastname);

    $Email = mysql_real_escape_string($Email);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
    $Lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($Lastname);
    $password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($password2);
    $Firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($Firstname);

    $password_length = strlen($password);

       if($password_length > 5)
       {

       $password = sha1(md5($salt.$password));
       $password2 = sha1(md5($salt.$password2));

       $Firstname = strtolower($Firstname);
       $Firstname = ucfirst($Firstname);
       $Lastname = strtolower($Lastname);
       $Lastname = ucfirst($Lastname);
       $Email = strtolower($Email);

       if ($password == $password2){
           $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
           if (!$con)
           {
           die('Could not connect. Please Contact Us: ' . mysql_error());
           }

           mysql_select_db("members", $con);

           $email_check = mysql_query("SELECT Email FROM users WHERE Email='$Email'");
           $email_count = mysql_num_rows($email_check);

           if(preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $Email)) {

               if ($email_count == '0') {

               $Email = mysql_real_escape_string($Email);
               $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
               $Lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($Lastname);
               $password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($password2);
               $Firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($Firstname);

               setcookie("Friendsplash", $activationkey,  time()+3600);

               mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Firstname, Lastname, Email, password, activationkey) VALUES ('$Firstname', '$Lastname', '$Email', '$password', '$activationkey' )");

               //$to = $Email;
               //$subject = "Confirmation of Friendsplash.com Membership.";
               //$message = "Welcome to our website! $Firstname $Lastname\r\rThis is a confirmation email regarding your recent request for a membership at Friendsplash.com\r\r
               //To activate your account follow this confirmation link:\rhttp://localhost/html/activate.php?$activationkey
               //\r\rIf you do not wish to activate this account please disregard this email.";
               //$from = "postmaster@localhost";
               //$headers = "From:" . $from;
               //mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
               mkdir("./usr/$Email", 0755);
               echo "<meta http-equiv='REFRESH' content='0;url=confirmation.html'>";
               }
               else {
               echo "<meta http-equiv='REFRESH' content='0;url=existing_email.html'>";
               }

           }
           else {
           echo "Please enter a valid email.<meta http-equiv='REFRESH' content='2;url=register.html'>";
           }

        }
        else {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='REFRESH' content='0;url=non-matching_passwords.html'>";
        }

    }
    else {
    echo "<meta http-equiv='REFRESH' content='15;url=short_password.html'>"; \\ Always taken here
    }

       }
      }  
     }

?>
```

I have tried commenting out this if but it then just takes me to the if above it.

Comment: **Which** of these statements has a problem? There are quite a lot in there. This is also rather unreadable without indentation.

Comment: I put a comment on the very bottom else which I am taken to.

Comment: if($password_length > 5)

Comment: Also, what was the unrelated part of the website that you changed?

Comment: I'd start by *indenting* this properly to be able to follow the logic. Maybe you're just missing a `}` somewhere. Better, restructure this to *fail early* instead of coming back to old `else` clauses at the very end.

Comment: Why don't you try printing out what is stored in password right before you call strlen on it?

Comment: @MikeOrtiz When i print the password it flashes data on the screen and takes me to another if statement: if ($password == $password2){

Comment: Voting to reopen. It's pretty bad code, but it's *a real question*.

Comment: @Nonym it was the page that the sign in would take you to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that you `mysql_real_escape_string` your data *before* you connect to the database. `mysql_real_escape_string` needs an existing database connection to do its job, if there is none, it'll return `false`. So all your data is `false`, hence your checks are failing. Read the [manual page](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) for details.

You should enable error reporting to catch such problems earlier.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Also, you shouldn't check the password length against the *escaped* value, since this may be significantly different from the value the user has entered.

Also, **fail early**. Don't have thousands of nested levels of `if`-`else` statements, it's unmaintainable. Rather, do something like:

```
if (!/* some important condition */) {
    header('Location: http://example.com/error-page');
    exit; // fail here
}

// business as usual
```

Comment: I have edited the code. Is it what you were looking for? @deceze

Comment: You still have the exact same problem as before.

Comment: Also what is the header. Is that the location to go to when fail

Comment: @Sne To redirect the user to a different URL, use the HTTP `Location` header. HTML `<meta>` REFRESH elements are a hack.

Comment: Thanks! I have been looking for a better solution

Comment: When you exit what happens? @deceze

Comment: @Sne Please learn to search the manual. [`exit`](http://php.net/exit) stops, ends, terminates, exits the current script.

Comment: Perfect fixed my problem and cleaned my code!